# Show that sequence is convergent. if $S_1$ and $S_2$ are two positive real number and $S_{n+2}=\sqrt{S_{n+1}S_n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> If  $s_1$ and $s_2$ are two positive real number and $$s_{n+2}=\sqrt{s_{n+1}.s_n}$$ then prove that sequence is convergent and **find its limit**.

I know that its solve by using concept of  monotonic and bounded sequence but I don't know how to proceed .

Please help!  The given  limit:   $\sqrt[3]{s_1s_2^2}$

Comment: You have asked enough questions here to know that you should format mathematics with mathjax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Try taking logarithms of both sides.  Then you get a linear recurrence in $u_n=\log{s_n}$

Answer (score 3):

Since $s_{n+2}=\sqrt{s_{n+1}.s_n}$, $\frac{s_{n+2}}{s_{n+1}}=\sqrt{\frac{s_n}{s_{n+1}}}$. Let $T_n=\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n}$. Then $T_{n+1}=T_n^{-1/2}$, or $log \left(T_{n+1}\right) = -\frac{1}{2}log\left(T_{n}\right)$. Hence $log\left(T_n\right)={\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}^{n-1}log(T_1)$, and $T_n=T_1^{{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}^{n-1}}$. That is $\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n} = T_1^{{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}^{n-1}}.$ Hence $s_n=s_1\frac{s_2}{s_{1}}\frac{s_{3}}{s_{2}}\cdots\frac{s_n}{s_{n-1}}=s_1\times T_1^{\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}^{k}} = s_1\times T_1^{\frac{1-{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}^{n-1}}{1-{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}}}=s_1\times T_1^{\frac{2}{3}\left(1-{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}^{n-1}\right)}$. It is now obvious that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}s_n=s_1\times T_1^{2/3}=s_1 \times {\left(\frac{s_2}{s_1}\right)}^{2/3} = \sqrt[3]{s_1s_2^2}. $$